# Chrome Extension click event handlers in popup capturing wrong target

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, dynamic-content

In my extension, I'm trying to make a bunch of buttons. Each of the numbers is a button, so all cells in the table except the header "Save" and "Load".

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
So my goal is 20 buttons, 1-9 (& 0) on the left that do a save action & 10 more that load. I made click handlers for each button and am generating the table dynamically.
Here's a section of the relevant code in my script linked from my popup html page

```
$(document).ready(populateGroupButtons)

function populateGroupButtons(){
    const groups=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]     //group 0 is at the end
    let table=$('#groupButtons')
    groups.forEach((group)=>{
            table.append(
            '<tr>'+
                '<td id="save'+group+'">'+
                    group+
                '</td>'+
                '<td id="load'+group+'">'+
                    group+
                '</td>'+
            '</tr>'
        )
    })

    $(document).ready(registerClickHandlers)
}

function registerClickHandlers(){
    let table = $('#groupButtons')
    for(let group=0; group<=9; group++){
        $('#save'+group).click((e)=>{
            console.log($('#save'+group))
        });
        $('#load'+group).click((e)=>{
            console.log($('#load'+group))
        })
    }
}
```

Popup html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-min.js'></script>
    <link href='css/style.css' type='text/css' rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Popup</h1>
    <table id='groupButtons'>
        <tr>
            <th>Save</th>
            <th>Load</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <p>Open console to see output</p>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='popup-script.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**I have it working if I view `popup.html` in a new tab and [it also works here isolated as a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SleekPanther/7Ljyyv6k/)**
**The problem is when I use it as a chrome extension, the table cell I click, isn't the correct target of the event handler**

- Right now I'm just loggin the target to console to see what's happening (I want to make the buttons actually do things later)
- When I click the 1 in the Save column, it logs `#save2`
- When I click the 2 in the save column, it logs `#save3`
- When I click the `<th>` which contains the word "Save", it logs, `#save1`
- Row 9 & 0 don't respond when clicked so appear to have no event handlers

**Basically, everything is shifted up 1 row and I don't know why**
It's working fine as pure JavaScript and on the fiddle, but somehow the target is wrong

**[Here's a zip folder of the entire extension](http://www.mediafire.com/file/ucvvq9mbitzuy04/Chrome+saved+tabs.zip)**

**EDIT: Problem Screenshot**
Look what happens when I click the "Save" cell.
**It should NOT even be a button because this is a `<th>` element**, yet somehow it registers a click.
Notice also, that it logs `td#save1` even though where I clicked was **above** the `<td>` that actually gets logged.
And after row 8 they don't even register clicks

[image]

Comment: Checked your code from zip folder and it actually works correctly, without any shifting. Btw, I would like to suggest you using `event delegation` instead of attaching event on each button.

Comment: @Deliaz I added a screenshot & more detailed explanation of my problem because it's still not working for me. I even removed the extension, installed it again, tried it in a chrome browser for another account and nothing worked.
And I know making a ton of click handlers for each button isn't ideal, but I was going to fix that later if I ever get the buttons to actually identify their targets

Comment: I got your problem and check again the code in macos and windows, just in case. And it still works correctly. Are you sure that ZIP folder contains latest/actual code?

Comment: @Deliaz I figured out it works on my laptop screen, but I've been testing on my 2 external monitors, that's when the problems occur. I'm on Windows 10 and all 3 are set to 1080p, but when I go to [whatismyscreenresolution.net](http://whatismyscreenresolution.net/), my 2 external displays show up as `1920 X 1080`, & my laptop screen is `1538 X 864`. Maybe this browser resolution vs native resolution. I also have `125%` scaling enabled in Windows "Scale & Layout", but I don't see how this should affect things. I want my extension to work on all displays, maybe this is an edge case but any ideas?

Comment: This case sounds interesting, maybe I will try to make tests on a different scale. You also can take a look for any related [bugs](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list) in chromium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally tracked it down to the fact that I had enabled `125%` scaling on my main laptop screen, but somehow it wasn't enabled on my external displays. (I recently got new monitors and maybe that setting didn't transfer when I hooked up the new displays). **Making them all `125%` or all `100%` fixes the issue.**

[image]

[image]

This seems like an edge case and isn't Chrome's fault, but this is the only time I've ever had problems with multiple monitors. I guess just something to watch out for.